# Alternative to RefFSContextFactory for IBM MQ + EJB to sending msg to queue

Tags: docker, jboss, ejb, ibm-mq

I have task to write code to get listener+receiver using JavaEE EJB 3.x+ JBoss(using Wildcat 14) + IBM MQ 9.x (MQ on my docker container). Write receiver was easy with all configuration for IBM MQ, using Message Driven Bean. And it works fine. I can send message from my MQ explorer in browser to my reciever deployed in JBoss. But I have problem with sender. I wanted to use `com.ibm.mq.jms.context.WMQInitialContextFactory` for JNDI Factory but it  is, in present, deprecated context(not safe etc.). People are recommending using `com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory` but it's a file context. It wants url to local folder for bindings. But my program will be deployed on other computer in future so I dont't want to using local file-context. Or I'm bad understanding positive in this way??

P.S. Before, I had task for same program but using spring boot and it was ultra easy using default spring boot context and *JMSTemplate.convertandsend*

Comment: Do not use WMQInitialContextFactory.  The ".bindings" file is just like any other file.  You simply deploy it with your application and other configuration files.

Comment: But can I use something simmilar to spring generic context? I only need to simple send message to queue to my IBM MQ on docker. File bidings for me ultra sucks. I need, on my MQ (in docker), edit JMSAdmin.config to add specific file url on my JNDI folder.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that I am a bit puzzled by your question.  If you wish to send a message via IBM MQ, you would first have a configuration like:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar" statistics-enabled="true">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:jboss/jms/MQConnectionFactory" enabled="true" pool-name="MQConnectionFactory">
                        <config-property name="transportType">
                            CLIENT
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="password">
                            redhat
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="queueManager">
                            ${wmq.queue.manager}
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="userName">
                            redhat
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="connectionNameList">
                            ${wmq.connectionlist}
                        </config-property>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
                <admin-objects>
                    <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/mqQueue" enabled="true" pool-name="mqQueue">
                        <config-property name="baseQueueName">
                            REDHAT.QUEUE
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">
                            REDHAT.QUEUE.MANAGER
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                </admin-objects>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
```

You would then either do JNDI lookups on your connection factory and destination and then send a message.  Alternatively, you would do resource injection and let the JBoss container populate your connection factory and destination.

Something like:

```
    @Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/jms/MQConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

You can use the connection factory and destination from JNDI to populate a JMSTemplate if you like.

Comment: Not JMSTempalte(because it's in Spring) but JMSContext. Yes, I learned day ago, that you can use default JMS context and not IBM context. But I have a question: some disadvantage going that way(using JMS default con.)?

Comment: You have JBoss with the IBM MQ JCA resource adapter deployed.  For inbound messaging - MDBs - you don't need any connection factories or destinations defined in the server configuration file.  For outbound messaging, you do use the connection factories and admin object destinations.  This is how the JCA 1.6 spec is designed to work.  Other ways are possible, but I prefer to stick with how the specification is meant to work.